# how could I reload websecurityconfig runtime

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot

I've use Spring Security's `WebSecurityConfig` to manager permissions.
and permissions just loaded once when the spring application started.

so how could I manually reload `WebSecurityConfig` in runtime when permission is changed?

this is my `WebSecurityConfig` code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
    {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/js/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/rest/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()

                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/boss/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()

                .logout()
                .permitAll();
        http.csrf().disable();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for your question ?

Answer (score 0):

Just get injected into WebSecurityConfig whatever you need. You can use @Autowire and @Value inside the WebSecurityConfig.

Comment: I have the same issue (I need Spring Boot to recognize users that were added after the application has booted up, and it seems this class is only executed once when it started and never ran again). Can you give an example w/code please? How do you invoke configureGlobal() from a separate page controlling login? Like from GreetingController.java example here:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/

Comment: @NoonTime Did you find any solution for you question?

Comment: @faraa I ended up using jdbcAuthentication. I added an answer below:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47232751/1363715

Comment: @NoonTime thank you... But I have to use jdbcAuthentication