# How can I register WebSecurityConfigs at runtime?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am building a web application for my studies. The application will be managed by a single administrator who can register organizations so that their employees may use it.

I already have a working WebSecurityConfiguration which redirects every unauthenticated user to a form-login-page at "/login". Now I need to give each organization its own login link under a path like "{organization}/login" since my professor requested it. And for that, I did not find a solution yet.

I cannot just add a page where users select their organization to be redirected to the corresponding login page since I do not want to present the information on which organizations actually use the application to any user besides the admin.

I tried to read up on StackOverflow and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38139033/how-could-i-reload-websecurityconfig-runtime). It does not answer the question I have since it seemed to be caused by just authentication.

I thought about solving the issue by adding multiple WebSecurityConfigurations (by using @Order) which ultimately does not solve anything since I do not know how many organizations (and which) will be added.

I tried using a custom controller to handle "/login" and letting Spring inject the HttpServletRequest into the appropriate method (annotated with @GetMapping("/login") in hopes of finding the original HTTP request that got redirected saved somewhere in it. It seems like I either missed it or it is not in there.

So my next hope is to add a factory to my application which just adds another WebSecurityConfig during runtime for every freshly registered organization. I did not find any means to realize that though.
So is there any way to register new WebSecurityConfigurations during runtime I missed? Or is there a place where I can grab the information about the HTTP request after they have been redirected to the login page? I am open to any solutions or hint to my problem.

Comment: *Now I want to give each organization its own login link under a path like "{organization}/login.* Why? Use one login and redirect the user to its unit pages. There is no need for differnt URLs.

Comment: Tbh I do not really want to but have to. The entire thing is a project given to me by a professor. In the beginning, he said that security is irrelevant but now no users should now which organizations use it. @dur

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I did not debug the session attributes properly. Spring Security saves the request in the session (accessible by the key "SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST"). Seems like I did only access "/login" directly and thus was not redirected. That attribute is obviously not set if the user did not need to be redirected.